# Return outside the function error:(Python)

Tags: python, arrays, debugging

Here, for this code I'm getting an error on return outside the function.
Can I anyone explain why is this so?

```
import numpy as np 

name = input().split(" ")
arr = [int(num) for num in name]
sum=[]
for i in arr:
   sum=+i
return sum
```

Comment: you can't use return outside a function.

Comment: As stated in the error message, you can't have return outside a function. What would you expect this to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` statement only makes sense inside functions. To show or display infos use `print(sum)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `return` keyword outside of a function. If you want to display the sum on screen use: `print(sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `return` statement outside a function. It is used to end the execution of a function and return the results of that particular function. You can simply modify your script to a function like this.

```
import numpy as np 
    
name = input().split(" ")
arr = [int(num) for num in name]

def function_name(array):
  sum=[]
  for i in array:
    sum=+i
  return sum

variable_name = function_name(arr)
```